# How to add timecode for time-lapse video

Tags: premiere, time-lapse

I recorded a video from 6:50 pm to 10:50 pm. Then I shrinked the video from 4 hrs to 1 min 40 seconds.

Now I'd like to add timecode on this video to show the real time,

I've tried to put timecode in a single sequence - drag it into the main video sequence - speed it up,

but the duration of the first sequence is too long (4 hrs), I can only shrink it down to 5 min 57 sec(10000%) at most, still way longer than my video length 1 min 40 sec.

Just wonder if anyone know how to add the timecode for it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I nested this video TWICE to speed it up